# How to reduce autocorrelation in MCMC

Tags: bayesian, autocorrelation, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm using MCMC to simulation the distribution of some parameters in a Bayesian hierarchical model, which has the following form:
$$\gamma_{ik} \sim Ber(\omega_{ik}).$$
Then I make a logit-transiformation, more specifically, $\theta_{ik}$ = $log(\frac{\omega_{ik}}{1-\omega_{ik}}).$

In order to incorporate covariates $x_{i}$, I use the following model,
\begin{align}
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
          \theta_{i1} \\
          \vdots \\
          \theta_{iK} 
  \end{array}
  \right)&=\mu + \beta x_{i} + 
  \left(
  \begin{array}{c}
          \epsilon_{i1} \\
          \vdots \\
          \epsilon_{iK}
 \end{array}
\right)
\qquad i = 1,\ldots, I \\
\theta_{i} &\sim N(\mu + \beta x_{i},\Sigma) \\
\mu &\sim N(0,G) \\
\beta_{K \times p} &\sim MN(0,\Sigma,I) \\
\end{align}
where $MN$ denotes the multivariate normal distribution.

I try to update these parameters separately, but it results in high autocorrelation. See the figure below,

[image]

Then I find out since $\mu$ and $\beta$ are not conditional independent given the other parameters, I should do block Gibbs sampling to avoid high autocorrelation between them. In order to do so, I need to calculate the covariance of $\beta$ and $\mu$ given the other parameters.

I tried  to do this in the following way: convert $\beta$ into a vector vec($\beta$) with length $K \times p$, but I failed to calculate cov($\mu$ , $\beta$ $\mid \cdots$).

My question is

1: Is there any methods that I can use? 
2: Is there any way to avoid high autocorrelation in this model? 
Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about how to tune a specific MCMC algorithm? If so you should probably tell us which one you're trying. Also, what's your reasoning behind including the $\epsilon$s?

Comment: @Taylor I included $\epsilon$ as noise, which follows a normal distribution and this leads $\theta \sim normal$ . I'm going to update all the parameter except $\epsilon$

Comment: If you didn't have that noise, it would be a standard Bayesian logistic regression. Just some other thoughts off the top of my head: if you're using RWMH, try tuning your proposal distribution. Also, try independent MH.